# how to make modal printable in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a modal with a table inside. How can i make table or the modal with table printable?

Thats how my html looks:

```
<b-modal v-model="modalShow" :title="tableTitle" scrollable hide-footer>
  <b-table striped :items="tableData" :fields="fields"></b-table>
</b-modal>
```

I am a newbie , easy ways will be nice :D

Comment: Not sure is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/mx2odn94/

Comment: Oh no , with the table display is everything fine. I think is a difference between my language and english: i mean really printable. I need a button who sends the tableinformation to the OS or browser. Just for print it out.
Or if it is easy enough--> directly to a printer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a library such as https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF to create a PDF of your table and then print this PDF. This also has the benefit that the user can download it and print it later on.